# Mutable variable in a Custom Class Provider Riverpod Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod

I kinda new to Flutter and I'm using Riverpod. Is it okay (good) to have a mutable variable inside a class that I pass in using Provider?

My Provider

```
final groupControllerProvider = Provider<GroupController>((ref) {
  return GroupController();
});
```

Custom Class

```
class GroupController {
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? myVariable;

  GroupController();

  Future<void> toDoWithMyVar() async {
    myVariable = ...;
  }
}
```

If its not good, what is the alternative? Thanks

Comment: This should be done with a Notifier and NotifierProvider.   The "state" will be the property being updated by various notifier methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your class is just a service/repository that won't be involved in updating state and rebuilding widgets, then it's wise to use a `Provider` for graceful dependency injection.

If your variable `myVariable` will be some state, based on which your widgets should be rebuilt, then

- in the simplest case use `StateProvider` | `FutureProvider`
- in case your state needs complex/several methods to change it, then use `(Async)NotifierProvider`

In the latter case, your code will look something like this:

```dart
final variableProvider = NotifierProvider<TodosNotifier, List<Map<String, dynamic>>?>(VariableNotifier.new);

class VariableNotifier extends Notifier<List<Map<String, dynamic>>?> {

  @override
  List<Map<String, dynamic>>? build() {
    return null;
  }

  Future<void> toDoWithMyVar() async {
    state = ...;
  }
```

You should probably also look into packages like `freezed`, which allow you to conveniently manage immutable objects. The fact is that for these providers to work correctly, your state must be immutable with a correctly redefined `hashcode|==`